# Choose $h$ and $k$ so that the system has no solution, one solution andinfinitely many

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Choose $h$ and $k$ so that the system has no solution, one solution and infinitely many
>
> $x_1 + 3x_2  =2$
>
> $3x_1 + hx_2 = k$

So I put it into a augmented matrix and row-reduced to get it in row echelon form:

$\begin{bmatrix}3&9&|&6\\0&9-h&|&6-k\end{bmatrix}$

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: So that the system what?

Comment: I assume you want integer solutions, in which case you will need $9-h | 6-k$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the last part of the title lol. Edited it

Comment: Your second line tells us that $$ \ x_2 \ = \ \frac{6-k}{9-h}    \ \ . $$  What values of $ \ h \ $ and $ \ k \ $ would make that impossible to solve?  What values would make it indeterminate (so any value of $ \ x_2 \ $ works)?  Otherwise, a single number can be obtained for $ \ x_2 \ $ and then for $ \ x_1 \ $ .

Comment: Ah ha! I see. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution when $9-h = 0$ and $6 - k \ne 0$ i.e. $h = 9, k \ne 6$

There is a unique solition when $9-h \ne 0$ i.e; when $h \ne 9$

There are infinitely many solutions when $9-h = 6-k = 0 $ or when $h =9, k = 6$

Comment: Yes -- just so!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

What happens if $9-h=0$, and $6-k\neq 0$?

Comment: no solutions i think

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The simpler way is to find $x_1$ from the first equation: $x_1=2-3x_2$ and substitute in the second equation that becomes:
$$
x(h-9)=k-6
$$

Now You can see for what values of $h$ and $k$ this equation has no solutions or one solution or many solutions.

Comment: Don't think that's necesarily easier.